# React Table - Cannot display a subrow that display same type of row as parent rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to display a subrow in React Table that has the same properties as the main rows.

E.g. A Row with the properties of "id" "persons" "age" "name" should display a subrow with the same properties.

I tried to use a subComponent as a prop for react table. It is possible to render a complete react table inside there, but that is not what I want. I want the subrows to be basically the same as all other rows. Just that these rows are grouped to the Row above it. I haven't found a way to this by using React Table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.